# Check if apache ran some Ubuntu commands

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php

I have a form upload page and the uploaded contents are saved to uploads folder. And i uploaded a file test.php through form and i could access the file by altering the link to /uploads/*filename* .

The file permissions are :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root          215 Apr  4 11:51 test.php
```

And the test.php file contents are :

```
<?php 
    $output = shell_exec("cd /var/www/html");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

And the file is being executed through browser it display the list. 
*So*, where could i find the log that displays these commands where executed because these commands doesnot show through history command.

Comment: There is, by default, no log of what applications gets executed by PHP on a system. History in your shell covers your shell, not your system. It's also trivial to manipulate.

Comment: I could use auditd for any write /read operations that will tell me which file was accessed but if some commands were executed and the file was modified. How could i know that what did the file executed i.e commands. ? Is there any other tool/program that might help?